# Python separate tests package

Tags: python, unit-testing, package

I have something like this:

```
/proj
├───docs
├───generated_data
├───sql_generator
│   ├───blocks
│   ├───generators
│   ├───models
│   ├───refs
│   │   ├───custom
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   └───tables
│   └───utils
└───tests
```

How can I include the sql_generator to run tests. I want to include sql_generator.blocks, models and so on.

Something along these lines:
https://github.com/joke2k/faker/tree/master/tests

If I run something like python setup.py test, it fails to import packages.

I also have everything specified as relative when I import a module. For example, in blocks, I have my **init** to import all modules and it may look something like:

```
from .block import Block
from .person import PersonBlock
```

Everything works fine when I run the sql_generator package, but when I try to run tests outside the sql_generator package, it will fail to import.

I've tried:

```
from sql_generator import blocks

from .. import blocks
```

Comment: Look at [tox](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for running tests.

Comment: @salparadise I am using that as well, but it's also nice to just be able to quickly run it sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have no `__init__.py` file inside of `sql_generator`, so it is not being seen as an importable module outside of the directory. Try adding that file into the directory and then you should be able to `import sql_generator` and the likes.

Comment: I believe I do have it, but I'll need to verify.